# Using Related Entries for Modular Content Entry

Tags: channel-entries, matrix, playa, relationships

Does any one know if there's a way to use data from other entries for modular content entry?

Meaning a user is presented with a Matrix-like field and they add a row and select WYGWAM to begin typing. They get to a part of their article where they want to include data from another entry so they add another row and select a "Hotel" entry for example. Then they wish to continue writing and add another row and select WYGWAM and continue typing.

Then on the front-end the data is presented as:

1. WYGWAM Body Copy
2. Embed of data from a Hotel Entry
3. WYGWAM Body Copy

The thought behind this is that the data for the Hotel Entry no matter where it appears is controlled by an entry and when updated is updated across the site wherever it appears.

Comment: You've pretty much outlined an approach that will work. What's the question?

Comment: How would I go about implementing this? The user entering in the data will need to have control over the fieldtype for each Matrix row they add whether it's a Playa relationship or WYGWAM field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both field types in the Matrix, let users choose what to use by entering content or selecting an entry from the Playa field, and then have template-level conditionals checking the fields for content and applying appropriate markup.